# Socket.io synchronous event listener client side + multiple function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, socket.io

I have NODEJS and I'm listening to event from my server on client side.
Each event update my HTML web page on client side.

But how to do it synchronously ? Because every HTML update must be one after an other.

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
  updateHTML(data);
  updateText(data);
});

function updateHTML(data) {
var html = document.getElementById("tile"+data);
html.classList.add("Class");
}

function updateText(data) {
var text = document.getElementById("tile"+data);
text.innertText = text.innertText + data;
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: When I receive 2 event from socket IO in the same time they are executed in the same time. I want them event to be ONE after ANOTHER.